# Insert data from multiple array form inputs using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have three fields

```
<textarea rows="2" name="answer[]" ></textarea>
<select name="fraction[]">...
<textarea rows="2" name="feedback[]"></textarea>
```

the user should fill this fields more than one time at least four times
then i use php to loop through this fields to insert it in database

```
$answer = isset($_POST['answer']) ? $_POST['answer'] : "" ;
$fraction = isset($_POST['fraction']) ? $_POST['fraction'] : "" ;
$feedback = isset($_POST['feedback']) ? $_POST['feedback'] : "" ;

foreach($answer as $key=>$value){
    $answer = $value;
    $fraction = $fraction[$key];
    $feedback = $feedback[$key];
    $query = "insert into `question_answer` ( answer, fraction, feedback) values ('$answer', '$fraction','$feedback')";
    $questions->insertData($query,$con);
}
```

this insert number of records , the first record  contain all values as i want but the other records only contain the value of the field related to the array i loop through and the other fields are empty..any help ??

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you give an example of how an incorrect row is appearing.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean when you say _but the other records only contain the value of the field related to the array i loop through and the other fields are empty_

Comment: Did you check that the user has entered _all 3 fields_ for each occurance before running this update?

Comment: He is overriding the values of his array in the first three lines of the foreach.. Of course he cannot access the considered keys and gets empty result in later loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite your variables in the first loop... Take this:

```
$answer = isset($_POST['answer']) ? $_POST['answer'] : "" ;
$fraction = isset($_POST['fraction']) ? $_POST['fraction'] : "" ;
$feedback = isset($_POST['feedback']) ? $_POST['feedback'] : "" ;

foreach($answer as $key=>$value){
    $query = "insert into `question_answer` ( answer, fraction, feedback) values ('$value', '$fraction[$key]','$feedback[$key]')";
    $questions->insertData($query,$con);
}
```

Comment: Of course the OP should prevnet SQL Injections too and make sure the user entered all data so that there is no answer without feedback or so.