# How to insert data into a database which uses the same input name variable for multiple rows in a table?

Tags: php, html

I am currently trying to design an invoice generator. Essentially the page has input fields along side a table which allows you to create extra rows to input more data.

I need this data to be stored in database to be called in the future to be turned into a downloadable .pdf

My current issue is getting the data from the table into the database. So far my code only inputs the first row of data. Am i going the complete wrong way about this?

```
<tr id="item0" class="item">
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='item_name[0]' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='quantity[0]' type='text' placeholder='0' class='form-control input-md' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='price[0]' type='text' placeholder='&pound;0.00' class='form-control input-md' />
    </td>
    <td>
        total
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="item1" class="item">
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='item_name[1]' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='quantity[1]' type='text' placeholder='0' class='form-control input-md' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='price[1]' type='text' placeholder='&pound;0.00' class='form-control input-md' />
    </td>
    <td>
        total
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the php...

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    print_r(array_values($_POST['item_name']));
}
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST as $val) {
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i];

    $sqlConnect - > query("INSERT INTO `Invoices` (`id`, `item_name`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ('".$i.
        "', '".$item_name.
        "', '".$quantity.
        "', '".$price.
        "')");
    $i++;
}
}
else {
    die('No item data to process');
}
```

Comment: Why do you iterate over `$_POST`? Number of keys in `$_POST` may not be equal to number of your item names.

Comment: the loop is wrong but @u_mulder it should still work for two rows - $i will range from 0 to 5.

Comment: How would i got about finding the number of item names instead? I found this loop example after hours of research

Comment: You can use `foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $i=>$item_name)` and do away with setting $i or $item_name separately.

Comment: Thanks, and what about the other 2 arrays, how do i include them in the loop

Comment: @Tÿler $i will contain the key in inarilo's solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert data from multiple array form inputs using php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985375/insert-data-from-multiple-array-form-inputs-using-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id field is an auto-incrementing primary key of your `Invoices` table: Leave that one, when inserting. Your current code always tries to insert 1 or 2 as id for every request.

If its not an auto-increment you need to generate a valid id in your app, `$i` alone won't do the trick.

```
foreach ($_POST['item_name'] as $index => $itemName) {
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$index];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$index];

    // DONT DO THIS! Its prone to SQL injection 
    $sqlConnect->query("INSERT INTO `Invoices` (`item_name`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ('".$itemName.
        "', '".$quantity.
        "', '".$price.
        "')");
}
```

Not sure what your db-connection library is, but currently your code is prone to SQL injection attacks. You should use prepared statements and parameterization. Please see what [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php) says.

Comment: This just gives me an error, as for the sql injection prevention it is something i have yet to look into

Comment: Who gives an error? php? database? What line? What message?

Comment: Thats probably just what you see in your browser. You should check the error_log file on your server

Answer (score 0):

To have a real dynamic form, where undefined number of items can be entered, you need JavaScript.
but for now, I would suggest to change your form to something like this:

```
<input name='items[1][name]'>
<input name='items[1][quantity]'>
<input name='items[1][price]'>
<!-- and for second item: -->
<input name='items[2][name]'>
<input name='items[2][quantity]'>
<input name='items[2][price]'>
```

so your $_POST data structure will be like this:

```
items:[
        [
          quantity:
          price:
          name: 
        ],
        [
          quantity:
          price:
          name: 
        ],
]
```

This way, you can loop through items, not item properties. and your loop will be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    foreach($_POST['items'] as $item){
         $sql = 'INSERT INTO invoices (name, quantity, price)
                 VALUES ($item['name'], $item['quantity'], $item['price'])';
         $sqlConnect->query($sql);
    }
} else {
    die('No item data to process');
}
```

Note that in MySQL you can set id field to `auto_increment`, so no need to include it in your query.

Also, use `var_dump()` to know what you are dealing with, like `var_dump($_POST)`;

Comment: I would use javascript if i knew how, i at least have some understanding of php. I also get an internal server error using this solution and it isn't because you have missed a closing } in the for loop

Comment: unfortunately i do not have access to error logs on my server

Comment: Are you sure? error_log is typically beside your php file.

Comment: I'm with godaddy so it has to be set up :/